# Best .NET datalayer framework for working with legacy databases

Tags: .net, database, stored-procedures, frameworks, legacy

I am building a website for a very old database. Because the database is a mix of different standards I've decided that an ORM isn't the right technology and will instead use stored procedures and views to interact with it.

What are good .NET datalayer frameworks for working with old legacy databases? Features I'm interested in are concise code to call the database stored procs and automatic mapping from results to strongly typed objects.

A framework that is light-weight and simple would be a plus as well. I'd to avoid something with the complexity of nHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option with disparate databases is to try to consolidate them in a newer standard. It may be feasible to use an ORM, I'm particular fond of [DevExpress' XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/) as you actually "code" it almost "transparently"... And it works with a LOT of databases:

Access 2000, 2007 (Microsoft Jet), Advantage Database Server v9.1+,DB2, Firebird 1.5+,
MySQL Server 4.1+, Oracle 9i, 10g, 11g, Pervasive.SQL 9+, PostgreSQL 7+, SQL Anywhere 11+,  Sybase Adaptive Server 12+, SQLite 3, VistaDB 4 and all SQL Server versions...

You can try ADO.NET with Entity Framework and use a POCO objects approach so that you can have finer control of the data layer yourself.

Again, I would certainly try to find a way to consolidate all data into a modern database, if you have to have the legacy application running over the old database, try to come up with an export process to replicate its data into a "queryable' modern database back-end... This way you'll prevent the legacy application from suffering in performance trying to compete with the web-site over the same legacy database (concurrency was not that well handled in many legacy databases...), and in fact it is sometimes the best design to have a "report" database (web-sites are almost always like a report layer) separate from the "main" working database.

PS.: Sorry for suggesting solutions without knowing your actual problem domain fully...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) Data Application Block.  It uses ADO.Net under the covers, but wraps it up in an easier to use package.  It's a lot more lightweight than something like NHibernate.

Comment: The MS Application Blocks are not something I would base code I'm starting to write... There is a clear path out of it inside MS itself... Just like WPF, it may become a corpse very soon...

Answer (score 0):

How about simply [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32c5dh3b%28VS.71%29.aspx)? It should support most databases. For older databases, there is usually an ODBC driver that will allow you to connect to the database. Which ones do you need to support?

Comment: I think he's asking for a more high-level approach than a provider.